# Allow implicit cast operator for const reference only

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make a custom cast operator only available (or only implicit) if the object is const?

Example:

```cpp
class Foo;
class Bar;

class MyClass {
    public:
        operator Foo() const;
        operator Foo() = delete; // this doesn't seem to have any effect
        // I also tried explicit operator Foo(); - no change
        operator Bar();
};
```

As you can see, I'd like `MyClass` to be implicitly cast to `Foo` if it is const, but to `Bar` if it is not const. This is because a pair of overloaded functions exists:

```cpp
void f(Foo x);
void f(Bar x);
```

And I'd like to be able to pass `MyClass` to `f`, so that the correct function is selected depending on whether it is const or not. This way however, I am getting an ambiguous call to overloaded function. Why?

```cpp
int main() {
    f(MyClass());
}
```

**Important**: I know that I can make this work easily by turning the cast operators into constructors, but unfortunately, `Foo`, `Bar`, and `f` cannot be modified. For context, this is an idea to solve my other problem: [Is there a way to resolve this ambiguous implicit cast operator overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924896/is-there-a-way-to-resolve-this-ambiguous-implicit-cast-operator-overload)

Comment: Non-const to const is implicit conversion which is probably causing confusion.

Comment: @Incomputable Yes but wouldn't that make this a double implicit conversion then?

Comment: What do you need this for? Maybe we'll come up with a workaround?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat See link at the end

Comment: I see two options. Either explicitly cast to `Foo` or `Bar` when calling `f`, or make `f` a template (with a concept checking for a conversion operator, and a helper function to select the right conversion). That should give you enough freedom to do what you want.

Comment: use the explicit specifier for your operator

Comment: Another option: keep the two overloads, but make them templates, with separate concepts that check castability to `Foo`/`Bar`.

Comment: Yet another option: do avoid this "clever" overloading to start with! At least, I wouldn't know immediately what is being called.

Comment: Does [proxy](https://godbolt.org/z/c64qbhnon) serve as a workaround?

Comment: @alagner No, the goal is to make a framework where certain classes can be automatically converted between one another, see link.

Comment: another option: provide extra `f()`, either templated or overloaded on value categories you're interested in, e.g.: like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/sT1T9qbfE). EDIT: sth went wrong, I saw your comment after adding mine. If generalized conversion is needed then that's not really helpful either.

Comment: @alagner Unfortunately, the `f` is actually a constructor of a class I can't modify. I probably simplified the example a bit too much.

Answer (score 2):

The best viable overload is chosen before its access and/or removal is checked. As there is no best viable overload with the original class definition it doesn't even get to that stage. That is, the ambiguity needs to be resolved for the overload resolution already.

Making one of the two conversion operators `explicit` does resolve the issue (with the test program there are still errors due to `Bar` being incomplete). Using a combination of `explicit` (and `= delete`ed although that is optional) conversions does yield a version which may be what is looked for:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo {};
class Bar {};

class MyClass {
    public:
        explicit operator Foo() const& = delete;
        explicit operator Foo() && = delete;
        operator Foo()& { return Foo(); }

        explicit operator Bar() const& = delete;
        operator Bar() && { return Bar(); }
        explicit operator Bar() & = delete;;
};

void f(Foo) { std::cout << "f(Foo)\n"; }
void f(Bar) { std::cout << "f(Bar)\n"; }

int main() {
    f(MyClass());
    MyClass x;
    f(x);
}
```

I didn't manage to create a version also accepting `MyClass const y; f(y);`: making the `const&` conversion operator non-explicit (for either conversion) causes an ambiguity elsewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really help me because differentiating between lvalue and rvalue references was never a problem since they are completely separate. The only problem is const references, because the others are also accepted as a const reference, hence the ambiguity. Your code works even if you actually delete the "deleted" functions.